# Can Windows Azure SQL Database handle large connection surges?

Tags: asp.net, sql, azure

I'm currently building an ecommerce website which will periodically need to handle up to 10,000 concurrent connections to the database and want to use Windows Azure SQL Database for this. From the documentation it all looks like it will handle this ok but has anyone had any experience with sending large amounts of traffic to it and how does it respond? Also the pricing seems a bit confusing. Can anyone tell me what kind of monthly cost this will be? The website will be built using ASP.NET.

Thanks

Comment: (1) An "x" factor is your code and database design.    Not all code is the same.   Not all db designs are equal.        (2) 10,000 connections is alot.  Are you talking about 10,000 possible users .. using the website around the same time?

Comment: There might be up to 3,000 users trying to check out at the same time with each page producing 2-3 connections to the database. I just wondered how Azure SQL would handle sudden influxes of connections and whether it would just fall over.

Comment: I'm interested in the answer too, because in our website sometimes the Azure SQL Database seems to don't respond, and a Timeout exception came out.

Comment: .NET is going to pool those connections for you automatically - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8xx3tyca.aspx. If you are asking about "Can my database handle 3K user interactions concurrently?", that is a different question and somewhat specific to your code/db design.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Standard SQL Azure starts to throttle you at 180 connections (among other factors).  Handling 10k concurrent connections to SQL Azure is pretty much guaranteed to not work, unless you find some way to pool them.

I suggest you look into running your own SQL Server on an Azure Virtual Machine.  Alternatively, you may want to try SQL Azure Premium ( http://blogs.technet.com/b/dataplatforminsider/archive/2013/07/23/premium-preview-for-windows-azure-sql-database-now-live.aspx ) - however, I am not sure if even SQL Azure Premium will handle 10k concurrent and distinct connections.

Comment: Concur - we tried using SQL Azure as our session backer and it failed miserably - throttling @ 180 connections.

Comment: Windows Azure SQL Database uses horizontal scale-out model - with the data sharded across many SQL Database instances. You may want to look at the Cloud Service Fundamentals sample and associated documentation from the Windows Azure CAT. http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsazure/Cloud-Service-Fundamentals-4ca72649

Comment: Thanks for the comments. My application will pool connections but I'm still concerned about this 180 connection throttling. I thought that Azure SQL would scale better than a stand alone SQL Server instance. The documentation makes you believe the database will scale automatically to handle large traffic spikes. Is this not true from your experience?

Comment: 180 concurrent connections is just one of the throttling conditions. With so many concurrent connections, and activity going on, you may be throttled on other resources before you even hit 180 connections. Make sure review them to fully understand the throttling parameters of SQL Database; I would most likely use SQL Server on IaaS in your scenario.   http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/1541.windows-azure-sql-database-connection-management.aspx#Reasons